# how can I make jqplot with selectable data points

Tags: jqplot

This may be basic but I could not find an example or API to make the data point in a jqplot graph selectable. Highlighter seems to know when the mouse hovers a data point but does not make it selectable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the plugin draggable.

Answer (score 0):

This post should cover what you are after, looks like you need to create some event handlers: [How to associate an event with only one object? jqplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491783/how-to-associate-an-event-with-only-one-object-jqplot)