# How to associate an event with only one object? jqplot

Tags: jquery, canvas, onclick, jqplot

Im using jqplot to draw some charts. It is a great tool, but it lacks a simple clickhandler option for each chart.

Its plugins like highlighter, draggable and cursor register their interest in capturing click/mouse-events from the jqplot canvas by adding themselves to jqplot.eventListenerHooks (eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotClick', callback]); for example. or 'jqplotMouseDown' or such are also available.

After making my plot with the usual $.jqplot(target, data, options);
then I do this

`$.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotClick', myFunc]);`

and sure enough myFunc gets called wherever I click on the plot, with `event`, `neighbour`, `datapos` and `gridpos`. Neighbour is the most interesting, it contains my data point if there was a click on it. This is the data I need to make a popup close to the gridpos with aditional information on the datapoint.

But the problem is if I have two charts on the same page and want to register different callbacks for each jqplot. As it is now, when I register the second myFunc2, all the clicks on the second plot go through the myFunc aswell!

Do I need to make changes to jqplot? Any directions, whatsoever?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't well-documented, but you can find a discussion about it [here](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/53/click-event-for-data-points).

Basically, you need to create event handlers for your chart **before** calling jqplot to create the actual chart.  To do that, you need to do something like this:

```
var handler = function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
    if (neighbor) {
        alert('x:' + neighbor.data[0] + ' y:' + neighbor.data[1]);
    }
};

$.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotClick', handler]);
```

That's just a simple event handler that checks to see if there's a neighboring data point near where you clicked.  See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/PtyFG/

**Update:** If you want to only listen to events on a certain plot, you could do something like this:

```
var handler = function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
    if (plot.targetId === "#chartdiv") {
        if (neighbor) {
            alert('x:' + neighbor.data[0] + ' y:' + neighbor.data[1]);
        }
    }
    else if (plot.targetId === "#chart2div") {
        ....
    }
    // etc...
};
```

Where you would replace `#chartdiv` with whatever the Id of the chart you want to listen to events for is.  The example has been updated.

**Update 2:**  Looks like you can use a regular `bind` event with the plot events:

```
$("#chartdiv").bind("jqplotClick", function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor) {
    if (neighbor) {
        alert('x:' + neighbor.data[0] + ' y:' + neighbor.data[1]);
    }
});
```

Example using this method, with 2 charts:

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/PtyFG/5/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I clarified my question while you where answering, I worked this out and it works great, if you have time, see my post above. How do I do for two charts where each has different handler? Oh, and thanks for the links! Checkin them out now.

Comment: Ah! I have thought of that, but it seems like a not so beautiful solution. The event is propagated to both charts. Im looking now at https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/src/a806b42e34e2/examples/barTest.html trying to get it working...

Comment: Gah! Seems the DateAxisRenderer Im using doesnt have handleClick.

Comment: Thank you Andrew!! I was snowed in on binding to jqplotDataClick. Doh!